# Required confirmations before newly received Monero can be spent

Tags: transaction-confirmation, available-outputs

I do not like to give exchanges the address for my cold storage wallet so I would like to use a webwallet as an intermediary point.

If I request a withdrawal from an exchange to mymonero.com how many confirmations are required before than same Monero can be sent again to my cold storage address?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Received monero can be respent after 10 blocks (see CRYPTONOTE_DEFAULT_TX_SPENDABLE_AGE). At two minutes a block targetted, that means approximately 20 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

It will depend on the exchange since each exchange can set their own rules regarding withdrawals.

However, assuming transaction is sent immediately when you place it on the exchange:

The transaction should show up on the block chain in about 2 minutes (monero block time)

It will appear as part of your balance, but not your unlocked balance until the transaction is 10 confirmations deep I believe.

So given those stipulations, the quickest you'd be able to move your monero from the web wallet would be 20 minutes from when you sent the monero from the exchange.

As a general real world answer, I'd say you should be able to spend your funds about 30 minutes after making a transaction.